# Display the Native Message UI in the custom iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, frameworks, message

I am working on a Project which has calling and messaging functionality.  Messages have functionality equivalent to iMessage. I have to create a UI for both Calling and Messaging like native iPhone system call and message UI. I found the Apple Callkit framework to display the system-calling UI for the app's VoIP services but didn't find any Apple UI framework for messages.

I need help to find out, is there any Apple framework available which I can use for messages in my iOS App to display UI similar to native message UI.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you attach an image about `system-Message UI` ?

Comment: System Message UI means iPhone Native Message UI.